# Is there a shortcut for switching between 2 open tabs back & forth?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browser, browser-tabs, tabs

I was wondering, is it possible to switch between two open tabs using a single shortcut, i.e. if x+y is the shortcut, then pressing it switches between two adjacent tabs. Much like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in Windows.

Please list shortcuts of all popular browsers, thanks!

Comment: I assume you have Windows 7 with IE8 ?

Comment: yes..I use Win 7 but use IE 8 is used seldomly!

Comment: This kind of shortcut would come really handy, when you are reading something on 1 tab and writing almost the same thing in your own words..probably editing some of the content as you go about it.
`ctrl+tab` & `ctrl+shift+tab` does the job only if the two tabs are touching each other, if they are distant..its no use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Firefox the add-on [Tab Utilities Lite](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/62581) can be used to get the required behaviour:

> Ctrl-Tab to navigate tabs in most recently used order, Ctrl-Left/Right Arrow in sequencial order

Answer (score 13):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>: to reverse cycle order.

And for the nine first tabs you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, etc.

It works in Firefox, Google Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Comment: In FireFox under Linux, it seems to be Alt rather than Ctrl for the numeric selection. Also, Alt (or Ctrl) -9 goes to the last tab rather than tab 9.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a list of hotkey whe working with tabs in IE8:

> The following table describes the keyboard shortcuts that are available when working with tabs.
>
> - Open links in a new tab in the background: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> while clicking the link.
> - Open links in a new tab in the foreground: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> while clicking the link.
> - Open a new tab in the foreground: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or double-click an empty space on the tab row.
> - Open a copy the current tab in a new tab in Internet Explorer 8: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
> - **Switch between tabs**: ***<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>*** to move forward or **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>** to move backward and **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>1-2-3-4-5</kbd>** to switch from one to another
> - Close the current tab (or the current window when there are no open tabs): <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
> - Open a new tab in the foreground from the Address bar: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
> - Switch to a specific tab number: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> (where n is a number between 1 and 8)
> - Switch to the last tab: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>
> - Close all tabs except for the one you're viewing: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>
> - Open Quick Tabs (thumbnail view): <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>
>
> [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20110404040531/http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows-vista/Tabbed-browsing-in-Internet-Explorer-8-frequently-asked-questions)

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to move forwards and backwards through the tabs on most browsers.

Another idea, which I find much easier on the fingers, and works in Firefox and I think Chrome (not sure of others) is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PgDn</kbd> to go through the list of tabs... you just need to ensure your tabs are next to each other for it to work (just like with the <kbd>Tab</kbd> combos).

Answer (score 3):

In [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29), no change or shortcut is needed. In all versions of Opera <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> switches between two tabs. The tabs don't even have to be adjacent; it is the last two shown. This works much like <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch between Windows applications.

(The shortcuts for cycling through the tabs in Opera were <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>2</kbd> in older versions. It is a little more complicated by default in newer versions, but I am using these old shortcuts.)

Comment: yes..this is exactly what I'm looking for! I don't use Opera that much. Is there any similar thing for Firefox, Chrome or Safari??

Comment: @detj: yes, see my other answer, http://superuser.com/questions/118326/is-there-a-shortcut-for-switching-between-2-open-tabs-back-forth/118666#118666

Comment: @detj you should update your question because it's not clear that you want this specific feature. They are many firefox extensions to achieve this and that should exist for chrome too...

Answer (score 1):

In **Opera** and **Vivaldi**, by default

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles between recently used tabs. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> to reverse the direction
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd> moves to the previous/next tab

So just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. No changes needed

---

In **Firefox**, by default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> switches to the next tab, but you can configure it to switch to the last opened tab like Opera by toggling ***Ctrl+Tab cycles through tabs in recently used order*** in options. After that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up/Down</kbd> can still be used to move to the previous/next tab like before. That means the behavior is now exactly the same as the default in Opera/Vivaldi

[image: Firefox tab option]

Old Firefox versions don't have this checkbox and you have to change `browser.ctrlTab.previews` in `about:config` to `true` manually

See

- [Changing Firefox Tab Cycle Order](https://superuser.com/q/18609/241386)
- [Switching back to last tab on Firefox](https://superuser.com/q/290704/241386)
- [I would like to switch between last used tab, not to iterate through all tabs, is there a shortcut?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1193670)
- [How to Enable Ctrl Tab Cycling in Firefox](https://www.solveyourtech.com/enable-ctrl-tab-cycling-firefox/)

---

In **Chrome** there's no option like that and you must use some extensions like [Recent Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ocllfmhjhfmogablefmibmjcodggknml), [CLUT: Cycle Last Used Tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clut-cycle-last-used-tabs/cobieddmkhhnbeldhncnfcgcaccmehgn?hl=en) or [Ctrl+Tab MRU](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ctrl%20tab-mru/ialfjajikhdldpgcfglgndennidgkhik?hl=en) for that purpose

- [Switching back to last *used* tab on Chrome](https://superuser.com/q/402095/241386)
- [How to make Ctrl+Tab cycle between last used tabs in Google Chrome](https://bumbu.me/ctrl-tab-in-google-chrome-for-cycling-between-last-used-tabs)

Comment: This answer is better than the marked answer, which recommended using a plugin to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To navigate between consecutive tabs in opera press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> keys. It's very simple and convenient to navigate between consecrating tabs in the series of tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Use [LastTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/lasttab/) in Firefox. I really miss this in Chrome as it is the fastest browser right now. The only reason I'm using Firefox is because Chrome doesn't have this feature/addon.

Answer (score 0):

For Safari you can install the [CronTab](http://www.ferryfair.com/crontab/) extension to cycle through tabs sorted based on the time they are last active. It also opens a pop-up of the list of sorted tabs.