# How to add new Firefox shortcut for Last Used Tab

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I trying to find a way through which I can add a new shortcut for [Last Tab](https://superuser.com/questions/290704/switching-back-to-last-tab-on-firefox). I do not want to modify the `ctrl`+`tab` to use the last tab. I tried installing Tab Mix Plus addon and even it performs the same [changes ctrl+tab to go to last used tab].

I want to add a new shortcut ctrl+alt+tab or something which would take me to the last used tab. Is there some addon that will allow me to get this ?

Answer (score 0):

In vimperator, default keybinding for changing to latest tab is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd> (find it in `:help changing-tab`). You can map your desired keys to it with `:map <C-A-Tab> <C-6>`.