# Chrome shortcut or extension for previously viewed tab?

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts, browser-tabs, extension

In Visual Studio I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (minus) to jump to the previous file I was reading.

Is there a similar shortcut or extension in Chrome, to return to the tab that was previously displayed (not the previous one in terms of order of opening, neither order of arrangement in the "tabs line", but the order in which tabs were displayed)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Switching back to last \*used\* tab on Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/402095/switching-back-to-last-used-tab-on-chrome)

Comment: [Is there a shortcut for switching between 2 open tabs back & forth?](https://superuser.com/q/118326/241386)

Answer (score 1):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is how to bring the tabs back.

Comment: I believe that this is not what the question is asking for.  But the question is unclear, so you *might* be right.